# Unity WebSocket4Net

Tags: c#, websocket, unity-game-engine

How can I connect a Unity client to a php webserver via WebSocket4Net dll?  I
tried an example like that

```
using WebSocket4Net;

WebSocket websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2012/");
websocket.Opened += new EventHandler(websocket_Opened);
websocket.Error += new EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs>(websocket_Error);
websocket.Closed += new EventHandler(websocket_Closed);
websocket.MessageReceived += new EventHandler(websocket_MessageReceived);
websocket.Open();

private void websocket_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 websocket.Send("Hello World!");
}
```

but got no result

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following links for more information on Unity and web sockets both for the general concept and for the specific to c# implementation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfdGw09-rC4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AifcMzEbKnA

https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/skeletal/csharp/supplements/Leap_JSON.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.Connect.html